# How to connect to different collections in solr from one Rails application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, solr, sunspot

I am trying to create a multi-tenant architecture and I am hoping to use separate solr collections for different tenants.

I am using sunspot-solr to interact with the Solr Server.

The sunspot.yml file looks as below :

```
production:
  solr:
   hostname: 127.0.0.1
   port: 8983
   log_level: WARNING
   path: /solr/collection_1
   read_timeout: 2
   open_timeout: 0.5
development:
  solr:
    hostname: 127.0.0.1
    port: 8983
    log_level: INFO
    path: /solr/collection

test:
  solr:
  hostname: localhost
  port: 8983
  log_level: WARNING
  path: /solr/collection
```

My Model looks like this:

```
class ContentMaster < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.table_name = "content_master"

  searchable do
      text :title, :stored => true
      string :id, :multiple => true, :stored => true
      integer :status, :multiple => true
      string :image_url, :stored => true
      end
end
```

And this is how I am fetching the content from Solr:

```
    @search = ContentMaster.search do
      fulltext search_word
      with(:status,1)
      end
```

Now, Everything is working fine for a single collection

Please guide me on the following :

1. How do I configure my sunspot.yml file to incorporate multiple collection(core) paths.
2. What changes do I need to make(if any) in my models to index data
   for different tenants.
3. What changes do I need to make(if any) in my data extraction mechanism for different tenants.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks...!!!